# Progressive Web App - All available permissions to date

Tags: android, ios, permissions, progressive-web-apps

Is there any kind of information about all available access permissions when developing a PWA such as Google Developers page ?

Till today (21st September 2018) we can acquire permissions from mobile devices listed down below:

- [Camera access for taking camera shots](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images/)
   Taking shots and display them via blob file. Choosing which type of camera we want to access (Front/Rear)
- [Camera access for streaming/recording](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-video/)
   Streaming a device's camera input and applying a CSS filters on it. Choosing which type of camera we want to access (Front/Rear)
- [Recording Audio input](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio/)
  Audio input. Applying audio/voice recognition, etc.
- [Notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/)
   Push notifications

What other type of access are available ?
For example, I would like to save a camera shots to specific location on user's device storage. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check your platform/device against this site https://whatwebcando.today.  You can see the different available features there and what is not supported